# Parse array of elements

Tags: python, arrays

I'm not sure the exact way to accomplish this, but I'm hoping someone can help me.  I have a string that's passed to my Python application.

```
string = '41_1,41_2,41_3,44_2,44_4'
```

Each of these elements (separated by a comma) are a row id, then a value (ex 41_2 is row id 41, value 2).

So for the above string I need to update:

```
Row ID 41: myColumn value '1,2,3'

Row ID 44: myColumn value '2,4'
```

Out of this, I need to come up with SQL syntax like the following

```
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = '1,2,3' WHERE id = 41;

UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = '2,4' WHERE id = 44;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        #Updating code snippet by leplatrem

        result = {'44': ['2', '4'], '41': ['1', '2', '3']}

    for (k,v) in result.viewitems():
        temp_list = [str(i) for i in v]
        temp_str = ",".join(temp_list)
        temp_str = "'" + temp_str + "'"
        print "UPDATE myTable SET myColumn={} where id={}".format(temp_str,k)

#Output

UPDATE myTable SET myColumn='2,4' where id=44
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn='1,2,3' where id=41
```

Comment: I don't think you read my original post.  The sql statements are wrong and will mean that data is lost.

Comment: @mattboston: Updated. Please check

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string = '41_1,41_2,41_3,44_2,44_4'
>>> bits = [s.split('_') for s in string.split(',')]
>>> for (key, value) in bits:
...     result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
>>> result
{'44': ['2', '4'], '41': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Comment: Now how can I get from


{'44': ['2', '4'], '41': ['1', '2', '3']}


to


UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = '1,2,3' WHERE id = 41;


UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = '2,4' WHERE id = 44;